# Using distutils to make a package sutiable for zipimport

Tags: python, distutils

I'm embedding python in an application that I'm creating and I'm looking for a convenient way to distribute the python code with it.  I recently read about `zipimport` and figured that would be a convenient way to distribute all my python code rather than including the fully expanded tree. So, I set up my package similarly to this:

```
.
├── setup.py
└── testpack
    ├── __init__.py
    └── pack1
        ├── foo.py
        └── __init__.py
```

where `setup.py` looks like:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='testpack',
    author='FatalError',
    version='1.0',
    packages=['testpack.pack1']
)
```

and then I ran `python setup.py bdist --format=zip`. But then when I look at the content of the zip:

```
$ unzip -l testpack-1.0.linux-x86_64.zip 
Archive:  testpack-1.0.linux-x86_64.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      183  2013-03-13 10:47   usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/testpack-1.0.egg-info
      152  2013-03-13 10:47   usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/testpack/pack1/__init__.pyc
      181  2013-03-13 10:47   usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/testpack/pack1/foo.pyc
        0  2013-03-13 10:41   usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/testpack/pack1/__init__.py
       33  2013-03-13 10:41   usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/testpack/pack1/foo.py
---------                     -------
      549                     5 files
```

Clearly the result is (not so surprisingly) not suitable for use with `zipimport`. Rather, this is a zip archive meant to be unzipped at `/` to install the package.

Is there any way to get `distutils` (or `setuptools`, etc) to instead build the package so that it will work with `zipimport`? Since the code I have is really application specific, it doesn't belong installed into the system library.

I realize that I can script it myself, but well, then what fun is that? For example, I want to make sure everything is pre-compiled and my package includes a unit test package that isn't meant to be distributed. So, I was hoping one of these tools could do it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`egg` archives are zipimport-capable (unless flagged to the contrary, in which case they'll be unpacked during installation).

Use `python setup.py bdist --formats=egg`.

Comment: Is this assuming `setuptools`? `egg` sounds fine to me, but I didn't think `distutils` can make them.

Comment: Works if I import `setup` from `setuptools` instead.

Answer (score 0):

distutils’ bdist formats are not designed to produce directly importable zip files, but rather distributions that can be downloaded and installed manually or by tools like pip.  You can use wheels (format superceding eggs), or use distutils to create the pyc files and then manually zip the build/mypackage directory and ship that.